# Connecting to pig from remote server

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm new to the Hortonworks Sandbox and I was wondering if it allows for an external connection to be made to it using curl from a remote machine to retrieve finished jobs or it initiate a new job. If it can, an example of using it would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried for some time and I keep on getting a login in page as the response from the curl request (even when I use the user|password command from curl using the appropriate credentials).

I am using a Hortonworks Sandbox v1.3 virtual box image that Hortonworks provides as a free download to run the environment.

Comment: are you talking about oozie workflows or generic M/R jobs?

Comment: just the generic M/R jobs

Answer (score 0):

Pig is not service, so you can't connect to it.
Instead of this, you can consider connecting to WebHCat (formerly Templeton) which has REST-API to hive, pig and several other components. Documentation is here: http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.2.4/bk_dataintegration/content/ch_using_hcatalog_1.html

If you're using VBox version, use 127.0.0.1:9090 to connect to webhcat, if other version, so use :9090

Especially look at templeton/v1/queue/:jobid to retrieve job status,

templeton/v1/pig to initiate pig job